# shape-rendering="crispEdges" still depends on the SVG width (Chrome)

Tags: svg

I'm drawing a simple chart with SVG, and I need the axes as sharp as possible.
The property `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` apparently works as expected, but resizing horizontally the window, both X and Y axes get blurred I'd say in the 50% of the cases.

Please take a look at this snippet and resize the window:
https://jsfiddle.net/Omiod/omak7t0c/4/

Looks like a Chrome bug as it works fine on Firefox.
Do you know any temporary fix?

Comment: I would use a `viewBox` attribute instead of `<svg width='90%' height='100%'>`

Comment: I opted for not using the viewBox to have a constant font size of the numbers on the axes  while having the chart responsive.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1072246 Chrome bug, which I think you opened.